# .Net Core - can't connect with WCF service (on Mac)

Tags: macos, wcf, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-cli

I am currently working on .NET Core 2.0 project (web api) on my Mac. I am trying connect to WCF service, so I followed all steps from documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide

When I am trying to use this command on the terminal:

> dotnet svcutil http://linkToTheService

I am getting an error:

> No executable found matching command "dotnet-svcutil"

I thought that I should have Connected Service inside Visual Studio (for Mac) but I can't find it either. So it's not possible to connect to WCF service by using VS for Mac and .NET CLI now.

Am I doing something wrong? I checked also this site:
https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/core/tools/?tabs=netcore2x#cli-commands

And can't find svcutil command for dotnet.

I tried to make it work just on basic console app (go through exactly the same steps as written in Microsoft documentation and still getting this error)

I also tried to install svcutil globally:

> dotnet tool install -g dotnet-svcutil

But console throwed the another error:

> incorrect combination of package and project for dotnet-svcutil 1.0.4

Comment: Did you install the svcutil globally?

Comment: Could you tell me how to do this? I thought that this command should work if I have just .net core installed and newest VS for Mac

Comment: Check docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide, especially points 3 to 5

Comment: @Tseng I did everything which is written in those steps :/. Added new ItemGroup with <DotNetCliToolReference Include="dotnet-svcutil" Version="1.0.4" /> (step 3). Then wrote dotnet restore (step 4) without any issues. But step 5 command "dotnet svcutil" don't work and I am getting "No executable found matching command "dotnet-svcutil" error

Comment: Installing globally seems to be not supported. [https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/3071]

Comment: @Menahem thanks for trying to help. So for now we know that it should be done per project not globally. One small step forward

Answer (score 0):

It's a dumb thing that tripped me up, but make sure you're issuing the command from the same directory as the proj file that you installed the tool with. You'll get that error if you're not in the right directory. Easy to miss if your directory structure is a little different from the Microsoft docs example.

Comment: I am writing this command in good directory, I've also tried to make it work on new console project as it's written in Microsoft documentation and I am getting same error.